# Javascript: All the promise in a loop not getting resolved which makes the execution hang/halt

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, promise

I have a specific case where I am looping over multiple artifacts and based on a set of rules (in JSON) I have to evaluate each of them, as the calls to check for each of the rules are async I have use promise.all to do some final steps after all of the rules are evaluated.

The code below is for evaluating rules based on type of the rule for one artifact.

```
Const promises=[];    
var ruleTest = function (artifact) {
        main.totalLength++;
        var config = RuleEngine.RuleConfigurations;
        // fetching rules and iterating through each of them to call has_attribute function or contains function based on the Type in the JSON config
        for (let i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
            console.log(config[i]);

            switch (config[i].Rule.Type) {
                case "has_Attribute":
                    has_Attribute(artifact, config[i]);
                    break;
                case "contains":
                    contains(artifact, config[i]);
                    break;
            }
        }

        Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
            console.log(values);
            console.log(main.contentList)
            // some final steps after all the promise are resolved
            main.loading = false;
            main.displayInfo = true;
            main.showInfo = true;
            //issuesFlag=false;
        })

}

function has_Attribute(artifact, rule) {
    var attributes = rule.Rule.MandatoryAttributes.split(',');
    for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        attributes[i] = attributes[i].trim();
    }

        promises.push(hasAttributePromise(artifact, rule, attributes));
}

var hasAttributePromise = function (artifact, rule, attributes) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // some async stuff
        resolve(value);
        }
    }

function contains(artifact, rule) {
    //some business logic
    promises.push(containsPromise(artifact, rule, blackListWords, whiteListWords))
}

var containsPromise = function (artifact, rule, blackListWords, whiteListWords) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        //some async stuff
        resolve(value);
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing is even with two rules (one of each type) the script exits even before the second promise is called and the page seems stuck as promise.all is never called. I have to implement this for multiple rules and the same promise would be created multiple times based on the rule type.

Strangely, if i create the promise using variable name and not returning it from a function, and i call it by the variable name in promise.all it works once for each call and then exits. 
for ex:

```
    var ruleTest = function (artifact) {
    main.totalLength++;
    RuleEngine.RuleConfigurations.forEach(function (rule) {
        console.log(rule)
        switch (rule.Rule.Type) {
            case "has_Attribute":
                has_Attribute(artifact, rule);
                break;
            case "contains":
                contains(artifact, rule);
                break;
        }
    })

    Promise.all([hasAttributePromise, containsPromise]).then(values => {
        console.log(values);
        console.log(main.contentList)
        if (issuesFlag){
            main.updatedLength++;
        }
        main.loading = false;
        main.displayInfo = true;
        main.showInfo = true;
        issuesFlag=false;
    })
}

  function has_Attribute(artifact, rule) {
    var attributes = rule.Rule.MandatoryAttributes.split(',');
    for(var i=0; i<attributes.length; i++){
        attributes[i]=attributes[i].trim();
    }

    hasAttributePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        asyncCall(()=>{
            //business logic
            resolve();
        })
    });
}
```

I have also tried using forEach instead of the for loop but it doesn't help.

I am very new to Javascript and I am not able to pin point the issue, so please help me out here even if it is a silly mistake.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/qifidit/edit?js,console). I filled in some of of the missing config and fixed some syntax errors to get there - this is the best I could do. I assume the syntax errors came from transcribing the code here. This *should* work. If it doesn't, then it's not really a problem with the code presented. Can you provide a [mcve] that shows the behaviour?

Comment: a stackblitz would help

Comment: @RaphaelSt it's always preferable to [use the stack snippet feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and reproduce it here. That makes the question self-contained and not reliant on external sources - if that link goes down, future visitors and potential answerers will not be able to benefit from it.

Comment: What is the `//some business logic` is `contains`, are you sure it is not asynchronous?

Comment: You should not use a global `promises` array! Declare it locally inside `ruleTest`, and `return` the promises from `contains` and `hasAttribute` instead of mutating the global.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with "const" instead of "Const".
'promises' constant is probably not defined.

Comment: There are other things wrong with this code like missing brackets. If OP claims it works in some conditions, I'd attribute those to the code being transcribed here. Otherwise, they be seeing syntax errors all the times.